# WPF Application freezes for 20 seconds

Tags: wpf, mvvm, async-await

I have a WPF (MVVM with Prism) application

There are quite a lot of factors that can affect this problem, but I will try to boil it down.
Hopefully I can at least get some tips how to trouble shoot this.

I have a user control containing a datagrid and a typical Search-button. The grid is initially empty and on SearchCommand. The user control uses a class "AccountServiceGateway" (_accountSG below) to make a request to the server, and then fills datasource of the grid with the result. Pretty standard.

VM: Binding command to handler in ctor

```
...
SearchCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await SearchOnServer(new AccountFilterDTO()));
```

VM, Button handler implementation

```
private async Task<bool> SearchOnServer(AccountFilterDTO filter)
{
   var searchAccountResults = await _accountSG.SearchAccounts(filter);
   //AccountSearchResultList  is an observable collection that is datasource for the grid
   AccountSearchResultList = new ObservableCollection<AccountSearchResultDTO>(searchAccountResults);
}
```

// Account Service gateway, making a web request

```
protected async Task<T> GetFromUrl<T>(string urlPart)
{
   ...
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    resStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //convert to T and return
}
```

**EDIT**

When I replace the implementation of GetFromUrl() with

```
await Task.Delay(5000)
return [hardcoded list of T]
```

everything works ok (although the hardcoded list is only 5 items)

**END EDIT**

Now to my problem. Getting an answer from the server taks about 1-2secs, as expected. I can follow the code until my datasource is filled. But then the GUI freezes for roughly (10-)20 seconds before anything is displayed, then efter the freeze, everything is as expected.

Other things to notice is that user control is in a Prism-region, within a Telerik RadTabbedWindow, so if this looks ok ith might be something else.

*So my main question is, why does it hang for 20 seconds, I suspect there is some threading problem, but if it where a deadlock, wouldnt it hang forever? Any way to trouble shoot this?*

Comment: Just a note, if you only ever create a new value for the AccountSearchResultList property, it is pointless to use an ObservableCollection. Using ObservableCollection is only necessary if you add or remove elements to/from an existing collection instance.

Comment: For your question, if there is a large number of elements in the collection, updating the UI may simply take some time.

Comment: @Clemens: Thanks for your reply. (1) Yes, I add and remove (2) I hate to say it, but this has worked fine before, its about 1700 rows and was filled easily under a second)

Comment: You'd have mentioned any collectionviewsource filtering. Right? That could be slow. So it was working OK. And now takes much longer. Maybe take a look in source control history at what's changed. Failing that. Create a new solution and narrow down what's going on in that. Forget prism and dynamic anything. By Grid I guess you mean datagrid. Just a window with a datagrid in it and port the bits of code you show us there. See if that works fine. If it does then your problem is in the telerik tab or prism stuff. Measure arrange for a  datagrid can take 10-20 seconds.

Comment: Yes, this was more a question about why it would freeze. If this particular solution of something along those lines could cause GUI to just freeze

Comment: Has the view changed in some way so that list virtualisation has been effectively turned off? eg. Parent ScrollerViewer been added.

Comment: You could serialise your data to disk. Deserialise that and throw it at the ui. If it's still slow then it's your UI. If it's not slow then it's not UI and and you have some threading or deadlock or some such problem.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: no,

Comment: @Andy: Will try that

Comment: @Cowborg: How is your XAML layout defined from the window down to the `DataGrid`?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: Hmmm.. .I take that back, you are probably right. I put the control (with my list in ) one step up in my hierachy of tabs, regions and controls and now it works as before... som something turned of list virtualisation  (Ill google it), Please write something like that in an answer so I cen set it to correct and youll get some credit

Comment: Thanks for believing in me man ... \*sobs\*

Comment: lol. np. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the view changed in some way so that list virtualisation has been effectively turned off?

eg. Parent ScrollerViewer been added

Comment: Yes, it was probably something to do with prisms region. When I went from control in region within a region to just control in region the freezing went away. Might write again when I know the actual cause, but definatelry correct answer (For me)